# How do two procedures (or macros) share one local environment in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

so my task is to create two procedures or macros (not specified in the assignment) in Scheme. Both of those procedures are supposed to modify a local environment that they share. There is an important condition that the binding is accessible only from those two procedures, so the procedures **do not** modify a global definition.

The task of procedure 1 is to set a local variable to a new value.
The task of procedure 2 is to add a number to the value that was set by procedure 1.

(proc1 5) => 5

(proc2 6) => 11

Here's what I have so far:

```
(define proc1
 (lambda (val)
  (let ((x 0))
   (begin
   (set! x val)
   x))))
```

I don't know how to get proc2 to have access to the local environment of proc1. My guess is to use either call/cc or a coroutine but I don't know how, can you please help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can two procedures share free variables that are not also global:

```scm
(let ((v 0))
  (define (inc) ...)
  (define (dec) ...)
  ;; both of them are available from here
  )
```

Now if you want the two procedure in the global environment you could `set!`:

```scm
(define inc #f)
(define dec #f)
(let ((v 0))
  (set! inc (lambda () (set! v (+ v 1))))
  (set! inc (lambda () (set! v (- v 1)))))
```

But there is a third option. It is how object oriented programming works:

```scm
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))

(define (make-peano v)
  (define (inc) (set! v (+ v 1)) v)
  (define (dec) (set! v (- v 1)) v)
  (define (message-handler msg)
    (case msg
      ((inc) inc)
      ((dec) dec)
      (else (raise (condition (make-error) (make-message-condition "Error: unknown message"))))))
  message-handler)

(define (peano-inc peano)
  ((peano 'inc)))

(define (peano-dec peano)
  ((peano 'dec)))

(define peano (make-peano 5))
(peano-inc peano)
; ==> 6
(peano-inc peano)
; ==> 7
(peano-inc peano)
; ==> 8
(peano-dec peano)
; ==> 7
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The second option suits my solution the best because the procedures should be declared globally. This isn't as complicated as I thought it would be! Your examples helped me a lot :)

Comment: @ElisaDay Thanks. If you find my answer helpful you should consider accepting the answer by clicking the [check mark beside the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)